# How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, codeigniter-3

My code is as below

In login controller I've used

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    /**
     * Check if the user is logged in, if he's not, 
     * send him to the login page
     * @return void
     */
    public function index() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')== TRUE) {
            $refered_from = $this->session->userdata('refered_from');
            redirect($refered_from,'refresh');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('login_page');
        }
    }

    /**
     * check the username and the password with the database
     * @return void
     */
    function validate_credentials() {
        $this->load->model('Login_model');

        $user_name = $this->input->post('uname');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $is_valid = $this->Login_model->validate($user_name, $password);

        if ($is_valid) {
            $data = array(
                'uname' => $user_name,
                'is_logged_in' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('/Dashboard');
        } else { // incorrect username or password
            $data['message_error'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->view('login_page', $data);
        }
    } 
}
```

and I want access this session variable in dashboard

My Dashboard is

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == TRUE) {
            $data['page_title'] = "Dashboard";
            $data['main_content'] = 'Dashboard';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            $this->session->set_userdata('refered_from', current_url());
        } else {
            redirect('/Login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

}
```

But it's not working 
I've added session library in autoload.php file

Is there any change in config.php file?

Comment: IMO, if this is being used to keep track of people logged in, then I'd install a reputable authentication library for this, rather than re-inventing the wheel.  See [Ion Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) or similar.  It handles everything and gives you access to class functions that will return a boolean, such as `is_admin()` and `logged_in()`.

Comment: Exactly sparky! I don't know why ppl are so obsessed with making their lives more difficult. With that being said, swapna can you confirm that your session is being set with a print_r($_SESSION) in dashboard?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Session data not there? redirect goes to the wrong place? You're getting error messages?

Comment: Please see this solution https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116089/login-system-with-session-using-codeigniter

Comment: i dont think the session could be create after u return the view, try to put ur 
$this->session->set_userdata('refered_from', current_url());
before the
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);